# ListStore add the same string to model

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

I have a ListStore and Treeview like this:

```
    self.listmodel = Gtk.ListStore(str, str)
    view = Gtk.TreeView(model=self.listmodel)
    view.append_column(Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Title", Gtk.CellRendererText(), text=0))
    view.append_column(Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Sprache", Gtk.CellRendererText(), text=0))
```

When you click on a button I call this function to append something to the listmodel:

```
def add_cb(self, button):
    pos = [["test", "deutsch"]]
    for (Titel, Lang) in pos:
        self.listmodel.append([Titel, Lang])
```

But when I click on the button a row is added, but both columns contain "test".
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the error:

```
view.append_column(Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Title", Gtk.CellRendererText(), text=0))
view.append_column(Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Sprache", Gtk.CellRendererText(), text=0))
```

must

```
view.append_column(Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Title", Gtk.CellRendererText(), text=0))
view.append_column(Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Sprache", Gtk.CellRendererText(), text=1))
```